# best solution for email forwarding when you have a cloud solution

Tags: email, cloud

I have some services running on OpenShift and others on a web hosting service.
I would like to migrate all services on cloud solutions to save money.
I found many solutions to assign a domain to cloud services, but I cannot find any solution to create email accounts or mailbox forwarders. When you subscribe a web hosting service you have these tools out of the box (you usually have an "Email" section in your CPanel), do you know any cloud service that gives you the same tools? Do you have to create them from the scratch using POP3 and IMAP protocols?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you: are you saying you can't find a cloud-based mail-hosting solution online? Really?